# Magento2 catalog:images:resize mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, magento2, magento-2.3

I am getting the following error upon running `bin/magento catalog:images:resize`

```
300/973 [========>-------------------]  30% 7 mins 100.0 MiB    | /1/2/12033_1.jpg
Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=17518 in ./vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
```

I am currently running Magento 2.3.0 on PHP 7.1

Does anybody have an advice?

Answer (score 0):

you need to increase the max allow packet in /etc/my.cnf add:

```
max_allowed_packet=32M
```

you can further increase it.